# How to disable cpu frequency scaling in Centos 7

Tags: centos, bios, cpu-frequency

I have tried all the suggestions here [How to disable CPU frequency scaling in CentOS 6?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324710/how-to-disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-in-centos-6)

However, the frequency still changes up and down. Even for CPUs I have isolated which are idle.

```
$ grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz     : 3201.523
cpu MHz     : 2197.091
cpu MHz     : 3575.810
cpu MHz     : 3521.169
cpu MHz     : 1675.158
cpu MHz     : 3559.854
cpu MHz     : 3079.546
cpu MHz     : 3092.115
```

and

```
$ grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz     : 2791.615
cpu MHz     : 3006.516
cpu MHz     : 2203.565
cpu MHz     : 2030.085
cpu MHz     : 1774.537
cpu MHz     : 3591.576
cpu MHz     : 3600.343
cpu MHz     : 3595.899
```

NOTE: the last two CPUs are isolated so basically idle at this time.

I have tried setting the BIOS to maximum speed and normal. I have tried all the governors and turning intel_pstates on and off.

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.60 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.60 GHz, 3.60 GHz, 3.40 GHz, 3.30 GHz, 3.10 GHz, 2.90 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.60 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative userspace powersave ondemand performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 3.60 GHz and 3.60 GHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.02 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

The current speed is usually less than the minimum, however, I have seen it as 4.0 - 4.3 GHz.